# django: fill checkbox based on url params

Tags: django

i am having a form with only checkboxes:

```
<div class="container">
    <form method="GET" class="form-inline" action="">
    <div>
    {% for temp in instance.menu_positions_tags.all %}
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" name="tags[]" value="{{ temp.name}}">{{ temp.name }}
    </label>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top:10px">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

When i select few checkboxes and submit the url changes to `localhost/test/?tags[]=day4&tags[]=day2`. After the page loads the all checkboxes are unselected.

Now, how to, in my form make day4 and day2 checkboxes checked.

Comment: You can simply add the list of parameters to your context dictionary in the view and check in the template if parameter exists in the list, and if it does set `checked` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `checkboxes` in your form file you can just render it from the form when you receive the `GET` request. And I think your form type should be `POST`.

Comment: I dont have a model form with tags.